# How to set up Unique Compound Index in NestJS (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, unique, nestjs

Hey i have a schema for user with an unique email:

```
@Schema()
export class User {
    @Prop()
    firstName!: string;

    @Prop()
    lastName!: string;

    @Prop({
        unique: true,
    })
    email!: string;

    @Prop({ nullable: true })
    password?: string;
}
```

But now i want to extend this. I wanna have Groups with their own users. I would create a collection of groups and add their id to the users like:

```
@Schema()
export class User {
    @Prop()
    groupId: string;

    @Prop()
    firstName!: string;

    ...
}
```

For each group the email should be unique. That means in the collection of users there could be duplicate emails but they should be unique by group which is named **Unique Compound Index** i guess.

How do i set this up in NestJS?

Answer (score 20):

Looks like its not possible to achieve it solely by use of the `@nestjs/mongoose` decorators, however its possible to declare index by use of `SchemaFactory`

```
@Schema()
export class User {
    @Prop()
    groupId: string;

    @Prop()
    firstName!: string;

    ...
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);

UserSchema.index({ groupId: 1, firstName: 1 }, { unique: true });
```

Then you must do either create migration to create this index or enable auto-index feature

```
@Schema({
  autoIndex: true, // <--
})
export class User {
    @Prop()
    groupId: string;

    @Prop()
    firstName!: string;

    ...
}
```

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to add a custom message like in my example: `UserSchema.index({ groupId: 1, firstName: 1 }, { unique: true, message: "User duplication error" });`

Comment: @buryo you can do with:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65625369/nestjs-mongodb-unique-fields-doesnt-work